# Which term is better to use ? さんじゅうにち or みそか?

Tags: words

My textbooks says the 30th is さんじゅうにち but can also be called みそか .

Is みそか often used ?

Which one do Japanese people use most ?

Answer (score 2):

I rarely hear みそか around me except 大晦日{おおみそか}, which is 31 December, though aged Japanese may use it.